Little master garage opener remote not working
How can I repair the remote as my toddler dropped it and I ran car over it..This is very unusual but it happened.
The remote works sometimes but not all the time.I see the blue light blinking without pressing the button, I opened the remote and everything looked ok except one of the Button stays pressed and due to which light blinks by itself.

Just purchase a new remote that is compatible with your opener. They are available many places and on the net.

Do you have a typo of the name in your title "Little master"? I question this because it sounds like "LiftMaster" which is a very common garage door brand.
